# SQL Server: How to modify a string to use it inside dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

I have a procedure in which I am passing argument as below:

```
exec dbo.procName @names
```

Where `@names` contains values like `'John,Rocky,Andy'`

Now I want to use value of the `@names` variable inside a dynamic SQL statement which looks somewhat like this:

```
  SELECT  ...
  FROM student 
  WHERE name IN ('John', 'Rocky', 'Andy')
```

I want to modify the contents of variable `@names` so that it could satisfy the above query and I would be able to use it like this:

```
'SELECT ... FROM student WHERE name IN ' + @names
```

I tried to use the `replace` function to replace `,` with `','` but it won't help too much.

Comment: use a split string function

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @names varchar(max) = 'John,Rocky,Andy,O''Brian'

Set @names = '('''+replace(replace(@names,'''',''''''),',',''',''')+''')'
```

Returns

```
('John','Rocky','Andy','O''Brian')
```

Comment: This would break if any of the names included apostrophes (quite possible e.g. O'Brian) - you could add another replace call to handle those, but I think a function to split the string and return a table would be cleaner?

Comment: @JamesCasey Your are correct and I'll make the change.  I too would opt for a split function.